# Cryptsetup language default bug during upgrade. How do I change it back?

Tags: encryption, 18.10, bug-reporting, cryptsetup, system-language

I upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10 and the default language for cryptsetup was switched from English to French (which is usually my second language on this computer). I changed back the language and keyboard layout once I logged in and even removed any other languages but English but cryptsetup still defaults to French. What can I do to get it back to English?